# Find lines that begin with tab in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi I would have some suggestions to find in a file lines that begin with a tab.
I have file like below:
text1
-> text2

I would have a lines like text1 text2

Thanks

Antonio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want match the line beginning with tab then use this `^\t+.*$` or `^\t+.*\n`

if u want to remove tags from beginning the use this regex `^\t+` and replace with `null string`

if u want remove ever tabs in text then use `\t+` (this will also match tabs in between words) and replace with `null string` or `space`.You can also replace with single tab`\t` if u wish

```
input: "`\t`text1`\t`text2`"

output if use regex `^t+` and replace with null => "text1`\t`text2"
output if use regex `t+` and replace with null => "text1text2"
output if use regex `t+` and replace with space=> " text1 text2"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Search: `^\t+.*$`

This will match lines that begin with any number of tabulation.